# Help me complete the solution to a geometry problem

Tags: geometry, triangle-inequality

This is the solution given in my book but it is incomplete.  What will be the next steps to complete the solution .
Edit- After simplifying the problem I now have  to prove this inequality . ((x+y+z)^2)>=6xyz
How do i prove this inequality  ?[image: Img]

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures when a problem is described. This is even an extremal case, where all the mathematical part is inside one picture. Pictures get lost in time, are not searchable, and there are some other arguments for avoiding them. So please use mathjax to edit in a proper manner. Also, what is the problem asking for and what did you try?

Comment: There are some typos in the solution. On the last two lines, $2$ should be replaced by $z$, and $PA/PB$ should be $PA/PD$ instead. As for the continuation, what is the minimum value of $a+1/a$?

Comment: I tried using Cevas theorem and tried to express ratio of sides in terms of ratio of areas ,  but these things didnt work out so i searched up the solutions  in my book . But the solution was incomplete so I came here .

Comment: I'll fix the typo. And which side is 'a' ?

Comment: Each of the terms in the square brackets are the type $a+1/a$. For the first one $a=x/y$. Then $1/a=y/x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the terms in the square brackets are the type $a+1/a$. For example, in the first one $$a=\frac xy\\\frac1a=\frac yx$$
You can use [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality) inequality$$\frac{a+\frac1a}2\ge\sqrt{a\cdot \frac1a}\\a+\frac1a\ge 2$$
The equality happens when $a=1/a$ or $a=1$. Putting it all together
$$\left[\frac xy+\frac yx\right]+\left[\frac yz+\frac zy\right]+\left[\frac zx+\frac xz\right]\ge 2+2+2=6$$
You get $6$ when $x=y=z$.